# Bootstrap 3 Complicated Nav Bar - A Toughie

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

After two years coding in CSS, I've decided to tackle my next project using Bootstrap 3. Most everything is going smoothly except for my nav bar, whose design isn't that usual (please see below). I'm having difficulty making it responsive.

When it's a mobile phone, I want to display the logo small at the left and the burger icon to the right. Then I want the red box with the tagline below it. But I can't seem to get it to collapse like that.

Here's my basic code. I have left off my efforts to make it responsive since those have failed and would only confuse people.

Can anyone think up a solution? Thanks!

```
<div class="bluenavbar">
    <div class="container">
        <img class="logo img-response" src="images/logo.png">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" role="tablist">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Issues</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Editorial</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sponsors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="redbar">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="tagline">this is the tagline. this is the tagline. this is the tagline. this is the tagline. this is the tagline. this is the tagline.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

--

```
.bluenavbar {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #23408f;
    color: white;
}
.logo {
    float: left;
}
.navbar-nav {
    float: right;
}
.redbar {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: white;
}
.tagline {
    margin-left: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: So, what do you want for the menu to do in order to be interactive?

Comment: Why do you care about the red bar being part of the nav?

Comment: jme11 nailed it below. The red bar is part of the nav because it was the design that was chosen. It's purely stylistic.

Comment: as for this situation, i would create my own style as bootstrap's just for standard uses. you can create style on style

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try not to make it more complicate than it needs to be.  Start with the standard mark up and add the Bootstrap classes to make it as close as you can to your design.  Then layer in your customizations.

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/oxswekp3/)

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-blue navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <img class="logo img-response" src="http://placehold.it/225x150/000099/fff&text=LOGO" />
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Issues</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Editorial</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sponsors</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    padding-top: 60px;
}
.navbar-blue {
    background-color: #000099;
    border-color: #000066;
}
.navbar-blue>.container {
    position: relative;
}
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 15px;
    height: 50px;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar-blue .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: transparent;
    color: #fff;
}
.navbar-blue .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #fff;
}
.nav>li>a:hover, .nav>li>a:focus {
    background-color: #000066;
}
.navbar-blue .icon-bar {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 4px;
}
.redbar {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: #fff;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.redbar>p {
    text-align: center;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .logo {
        height: auto; /*or whatever height you want it*/
    }
    .redbar {
        margin-bottom: 75px;
    }
    .redbar>p {
        max-width: 500px;
    }
}
```

So here I used a pretty basic navbar that I cut and pasted from the doc.  Then I added the `.navbar-fixed-top` class to make it stick to the top of the viewport.  As described in the doc, I added some padding to the top of the body to adjust for using the navbar-fixed-top class.  I then removed the extraneous links that were in the example and substituted your links in the ul that had the `.navbar-right` class on it, which floats the links to the right of the navbar.

From there, I replace the navbar-brand with a logo image and gave it absolute positioning so that it would be "on top" of the other elements, sized it for the mobile view, and used a media query to control it's size when the viewport was more than 768px (remember to try to think mobile-first).  I also gave the element inside the navbar that has the  `.container` class position relative so that the logo would align to the inside of the container on the left.

Next, I created a custom class called `.navbar-blue` and styled it to have the colors that roughly matched your image.  I just copied the .navbar-default styles out of the bootstrapcss file and changed the colors, but normally I would use LESS to customize my colors.  If you know LESS or SASS already, you'll love the support that Bootstrap offers for both.

Lastly, I just created the red bar with some basic styles: done and dusted.

Comment: Wow, this was insanely helpful. And you're right. I think I'm trying too hard to fit my design into Bootstrap as opposed to using it as one of the ways to get the design coded. I really appreciate that you took the time to do this AND explain everything. If I can be of any help down the road, let me know! Thanks again!!

Comment: You're welcome and good luck with it...trust me, seem a bit daunting in the beginning, but it gets a lot easier as you work through a project or two using Bootstrap as the foundation.

Comment: I know. I'll just keep beating my head against the wall and right before passing out, I'll have figured everything out.

I'm still trying to figure out what happened to the hamburger icon. I pasted your code into mine and everything work flawlessly excite for that icon. It doesn't appear. But I'll figure it out!

Comment: I figured out the hamburger problem. I needed to use "glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify" instead of the one you had, which wasn't being recognized. One problem solved, another presents itself: It's now too small. Onward!

Comment: Sorry, you're correct.  It's so natural for me to swap out the toggle with a font-icon, I did it without realizing.  I put the standard markup in the demo and answer above using the span elements with the .icon-bar class, and added the styles to make them slightly larger and white just by adding a single rule as follows: .navbar-blue .icon-bar {background-color: #fff; height: 4px;}.